# Plot google map as background

Tags: python, image, google-maps, url

I want to display Google map and I use this code :

```
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.027489,-51.229248&size=800x800&zoom=14&sensor=false"
im = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()))
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

this gives me:[image]

Which I don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of `imshow()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) and specifically its `origin` argument which determines where the [0,0] index of the array is located in the plot.

The line needs to be:

```
plt.imshow(im, origin='upper')
```